# Anuglar Ng-repeat get properties inside object's object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem on getting properties inside of an object of an object of an object of an array....Sorry this is too complex...

This is how's my array looks like:

> Many Object in one array:

```
Array [ Object , Object ]
```

> Each Object have a "pair1" and "pair2" Object

```
Array [ [ pair1 , pair2] , Object ]
```

> Each "pair" have a "player1" and "player2" Object

```
Array [ [ [ player1, player2 ] , pair2 ] , Object ]
```

> Each "player" have many properties

```
Array [ [ [ {id:1, firstname:"test", ...} , player2 ] , pair2 ] , Object ]
```

[image: For yours convenience]

And I will like to have a result like:
[image]

The variable of my Array is:
    $scope.currentList = Array [ Object , Object ]

And I tried to do in this way, but is not working?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="success">
        <td>Team 1</td>
        <td>Team 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="match in currentList">
        <td>
            {{match.pair1.player1.firstname}}<br>
            {{match.pair1.player2.firstname}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{match.pair2.player1.firstname}}<br>
            {{match.pair2.player2.firstname}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use directive for subtable.

Comment: Do you mean I should have a table inside of td?

Comment: thank you @Damiano, but is not working?

Comment: Can u post the screenshot of what you are having after using this code ?

Comment: Try to debug it slowly - first add only {{match}} to your <td>, then {{match.pair1}} and so on... I bet your problem is in the match object itself

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I have sth. with {{match}} but not with {{match.pair1}}, I didn't know that we can do it like this,hahaha

Comment: Thank you so much @Damiano, {{match[0].pair1.player1.firstname}} works!! How can I vote you as best answer??

Comment: 'Thank you' is enough :)

Comment: **Thank You** Very much, good person you are!

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-repeat inside ng-repeat. because your structure of an aray is multilevel and you have specified variable name so I can give you this much information.

Answer (score 0):

Damiano is explained correctly,

still I tried some following, try this.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/Lvc0u55v/8344/) is working fiddle

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped" border="1">
    <tr class="success">
        <td></td>
        <td>Pair 1</td>
        <td>Pair 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in currentList">
        <td>
          Match {{key+1}}
        </td>
        <td>
           <span ng-repeat="(pairKey,pairVal) in value.pair1">
             {{pairVal.name}} <br>
           </span>
        </td>
        <td>
           <span ng-repeat="(pairKey,pairVal) in value.pair2">
             {{pairVal.name}} <br>
           </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.currentList = [{pair1:{player1:{name:'Ashish',age:25},player2:{name:'sachin',age:25}},
                         pair2:{player1:{name:'Anil',age:25},player2:{name:'Kamal',age:25}}},
                         {pair1:{player1:{name:'AMol',age:20},player2:{name:'Santosh',age:21}},
                         pair2:{player1:{name:'satish',age:20},player2:{name:'Devidas',age:21}}}];
   console.log($scope.currentList);


}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your solution,  I do not have any output, {{value.pair1}} is not working, {{value[0].pair1}} does work